# How to check if an id-String is included in an array of mongoose ObjectIds?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, ecmascript-6

My code is somewhat inconsistent since I have one array of ObjectIds an one array of Ids as Strings.

```
array1 = [new ObjectId("2"), new ObjectId("3"), new ObjectId("4")]

array2 = ["1","4"]
```

I want to iterate over array2 and check, if the Id is included in array1 (using "includes", I could loop inside loop but that's what I try to avoid). Unfortunately
"includes" seems to be Type-sensitive.

```
array2.map(id => {array1.inclundes(id) && console.log("is included!"})
```

does not work
as well as:

```
array2.map(id => {array1.includes(mongoose.Tyes.ObjectId(id)) && console.log("is included"})
```

which I thought would convert the "id" in the proper Type for comparison.

What works is:

```
array2.map(id2 => {
    array1.map(id1 => {
        if(id1 == id2){
            console.log("included")
        }
    })
})
```

While the following also don't work:

```
array2.map(id2 => {
    array1.map(id1 => {
        if(id1 === id2){
            console.log("included")
        }
    })
})
```

So I think there is a Type-related Error even if both are "Object" after `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)`

Comment: make another map of array1, array1_mod = array1.map(oid => oid.toString()). This will give you a list which has string ids and you can use includes on that.

Comment: in order to back what *gyan roy* already suggested ... [`ObjectId` Methods and Attributes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#methods-and-attributes)